# How to generate List of random numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I want to generate a list of random numbers in Haskell.

```
Step 1 : declare an empty Int List 
Step 2 : Generate a random number between 1 to 50
Step 3 : Add that number at the end of the List.
Step 4 : Repeat Step 2 and 3 for 5 times.
```

I have written the code using an Array.

```
import System.Random 
import Data.Array.IO
main =  do 
     arr <- newArray (1,5) 0 :: IO (IOArray Int Int)

     forM_ [1..5] (\i -> do
        v <- getStdRandom(randomR (1,50))
        writeArray arr i v)

     forM_ [1..5] (\i -> do 
        a <- readArray arr i        
        print (a))
```

A sample output is like this: -

```
Prelude> main
32
14
27
23
33
```

**How to implement this using a List. May be using MVar or TVar List.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way to think about this is not to say "start with an empty list and then fill it up", but rather "A list of N random numbers consists of a single random number followed by a list of N-1 random numbers". What you have written is the translation of what you would write in Java or C++.

Comment: The [Data.Random.Normal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/normaldistribution-1.1.0.1/docs/Data-Random-Normal.html) module lets you do something like `mkNormals 12345` to get an infinite list of random values (12345 is the seed).

Comment: Thank you @FrerichRaabe. I am using GHC. And I have to  install Data.Random.Normal for ghc, isn't it?

Comment: Right @AmmlanGhosh -- the `Data.Random.Normal` module is part of th `normaldistribution` package, so you could run `cabal install normaldistribution` to install that and then you'd have access to the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Step 1 : declare an empty `Int` List...

don't do that. Creating an empty thing an then filling it up is seldom a good idea. Sometimes, for performance reasons, it can be clever to create an *uninitialised array* (not empty, but "vacuous") and then define the contents after the fact – that's basically what happens in you code. Also reasonable: starting with an empty `Set` and progressively filling it up; this can be done nicely in a purely-functional state monad.

But for lists (or arrays), starting empty never gains you anything; why not properly define the *full* result list straight away? It's as simple as this:

```
    do
      ...
      randList <- forM [1 .. lLength] $ \_i -> randomRIO (1,50)
      ...
```

Note that this is not `forM_` but `forM`, which automatically gathers the results in a list – just what you want! I don't actually need the index parameter (hence the `_` prefix of the `i` variable). I could also have written `mapM (const $ randomRIO (1,50)) [1 .. lLength]`, or indeed simply `replicateM lLength $ randomRIO (1,50)`, as user3237465 remarks.

Comment: If you don't need the index parameter, then you can write just `replicateM lLength (randomRIO (1,50))`.

Comment: Another (probably more concise) variant is to generate an infinite list of random elements and then take a desirable amount:
`liftM (take 10 . randomRs (1, 50)) getStdGen`

Comment: @Yuuri: right. Careful with `getStdGen`, though, I don't think it's safe to use it in this way... you want to make sure later parts of the program receive a different seed (either by explicitly propagating/splitting the generator, or having one of the `IO` actions do it for you, or a dedicated [random monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.3.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html)). Neither happens in your snippet.